# VBA Excel Loop will not handle array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

****UPDATE THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED***** Thanks everyone for your help to lead me to this conclusion!******

So everything in my code as seen below does as intended except for one line.

`If c = myArray(x) Then`

This script reads in a file that I have left unmentioned. It reads the 'A' column from the file and throws each row into `myArray`. I know the array works because when I loop it out into dialogue boxes it prints out the data properly. The loop functions properly searching for each row, if it's equal to 'c' it grabs my data and puts it in another sheet. I know this works because when I just enter in the data it grabs it as intended. My trouble is whenever I try to add in the element of `myArray(x)` to compare it with integer 'c'. It refuses to look at the x integer to properly loop through `myArray()` with integer 'x'.

Can someone please explain to me why `myArray(x)` will not loop properly or help me with a solution. I am not a veteran VBA programmer but I have written my fair share of code that functions just fine. I just feel like I am missing a minor detail and have overlooked something simple. Any help at all would be appreciated this is for work purposes and you'd be helping others not just myself.

```
Sub myArray()
    Dim FSO As Object, MyFile As Object
    Dim FileName As String, Arr As Variant
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer, i as Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet

    FileName = ""   '<--This is left intentionally blank.
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
    Arr = Split(MyFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)  
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    i = 0
    j = 1

   For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    For Each c In Source.Range("B:D")
        If c = Arr(i) Then
            Source.rows(c.Row).Copy Target.rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of ***x*** when the error occurs ??

Comment: Think you should add check on line `If c = myArray(x) Then` to evaluate if it is not exceeding array's upper bound. Something like `If c = myArray(x) and x <= ubound(myArray) Then`.

Comment: X = 0 as is it should.

If c = myArray(x) and x <= ubound(myArray) Then

This did not work for my For loop it still will not compare the values.

Comment: I have found the solution and posted my code above that reflects what I truly wanted. I needed nested for loops. Thanks everyone for helping me come to this conclusion. Thanks @Chris Mack for helping me with ubounds and string conversions. I now know more about vba programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're likely to keep checking the array after you've incremented `x` past its upper bound, as that loop is independent of the `B1:D6719` loop.

Would it be a case of amending the code to something like:

```
For Each c In Source.Range("B1:D6719")
    If c = CInt(myArray(x)) Then '<--Here is where my problem is, this line right here
        Source.rows(c.Row).Copy Target.rows(j)
        j = j + 1
        x = x + 1
    End If

    If x > UBound(myArray) Then Exit For
Next c
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I tried both ways as shrivallabha mentioned above as well. The loops does just not recognize integer 'x' in my array, When I print out x it is equal to 0 as it should be.

Comment: If you are comparing integers you will need to use `CInt`, as your array is a string array. See my updated code.

Comment: So this is now saying its a data type mismatch, so I tried CLng and even CStr. The datatype would have to a be a long as the numbers im looking up are large. This still does not function properly as I want it to. It no longers spits out any errors. The program runs and it still refuses to look at my array(x) and grab any rows that contain the data i want in columns B:D and move it to sheet 2. When I put in the number manually it runs just fine. What is wrong with my array???

Comment: Could you upload a workbook or something? Just something basic that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm unable to access that without Gmail. Do you have Dropbox, Google Drive, or anything like that?

Comment: I have found the solution and posted my code above that reflects what I truly wanted. I needed nested for loops. Thanks everyone for helping me come to this conclusion. Thanks @Chris Mack for helping me with ubounds and string conversions. I now know more about vba programming.

Comment: Cool - and no problem!

Answer (score -2):

Try calling the array starting by 1:

```
    x = 1
    if c = myArray(x) then
```

on others [examples of array in vba](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html) I have seen that they start on 1 instead of 0

Comment: Sorry I've tried to use 1 as the starting point, this is indeed not the case. Like I said my array functions just fine its the For loop that is not spooling through the array properly